# Simplify Magento 2 search engine results

Tags: magento2.3, search

new to Magento 2 and this forum for now.

In the company I work, we have a website on Magento 2.3.4, migrated from Magento 1 , and cause I know some English the boss here wants me to make some improvements. What I'm interested in is how to modify the search engine to display less results from a search in the Magento 2 search engine.

For example: - I type: "Ролка за преместване на Товари" on my native language and it displays me 1500 results, containing all the keywords.

The words on my native language means - "rollers for moving loads", and we have this products with the exactly same name in the "Magento 2 Catalog" but it displays all the results containing these keywords.

Usually even the products are not in the top results even.

So my question is, how I can somehow modify the search engine, to display less products in the results, and to display firstly the associated products to the keywords from our catalog of products.

Any Ideas? Anybody? (angel emote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catalog search relevance and search results in native Magento2 Open Source are notoriously bad - a simple SKU / keyword search is a great example of Magento2 returning very poor search results.

There are ways to fine tune Elastisearch and improve relevance but by far the best solution is to use

https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

> Simply put, installing the Smile ElasticSuite modules and changing
> catalog search to ElasticSuite will immediately give you almost
> perfect search results. ElasticSuite is very simple to install and
> works out of the box improving search results and search relevance.

I wrote a blog post about this that describes in detail the problems with SKU search and the options I looked at to try and improve default search myself.

https://blog.gaiterjones.com/how-to-improve-magento-2-elasticsearch-catalog-search-results-and-relevance/

Comment: Thank you man (virtual hug), will try it just in a moment.