# Product search in magento 2 is not working properly

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

Problem is  that when we search Keyword 'T Shirt' then its working fine but when we change keyword like 'Tshirt' then it's not working.
Can any one help me on this query.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Default Magento 2 catalog search provides very poor search results. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332254/simplify-magento-2-search-engine-results/332256#332256

Comment: @paj elastic Search Installed but not working?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307365/34579 - give it a try on this solution one if it helps.